# How to attach a 4x4 deck railing post above a 6x6 support post

Tags: framing, deck

I have a raised deck that I'm building at my house. Normally, when building a deck, I use a beam located below the deck on which the deck joists sit. In this case, I have a situation where I'd like to have the beam level with the deck where all joists are connected to that beam. There is a basement door below the deck and I need the extra headroom. In this situation, 2 of the deck support posts would be in the corners due to limitations of footer placement.

This particular construction scenario poses a problem that I need some help with...In the past, I would always attach the deck railing posts on the inside corners of the deck using bolts and blocking so that it is a strong connection. In this case, the deck support post would not allow that to happen. If the support post is notched and bolted to the beam OR a Simpson Strong Tie to beam connector is used on on top of the post, it prevents me from attaching the corner railing post. Either the notched post and bolts or Simpson Strong Tie connector would be obstructing the post. The only attachment in this scenario would be for the railing post to be sitting on top of the deck and screwed in resulting in a weak connection.

I searched and ran across [this](https://www.decks.com/how-to/articles/anatomy-of-a-deck) diagram from the decks.com website that shows a similar situation. The only difference being a single joist on the sides. The diagram is misleading because the post cap connector shown is much shorter than they really are. Anyway, I hope this all makes sense and any help you can provide is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Pictures or diagrams are always nice to have.. helps us to see what you see.

Comment: Your link takes me to a page without any images. Want to [edit] and try again?